# Change the orientation recyclerview card size change

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, android-nestedscrollview, screen-rotation

I have a `RecyclerView` with `GrideLayoutManger`. When I rotate the phone, the RecyclerView item card size changes.

How can I solve this problem?

Actual card size before rotating phone:

[image]

After rotating the phone:

[image]

Comment: Please add your code so we can see what you did so far.

Comment: Try to use setHasFixedSize(true) on your recyclerview

Comment: Please add your recyclerview and adapter code

Comment: change the width of the card to match_parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make image size static,In wrap content it cause compress. set fix size to your root view it solve problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your items root width is `wrap_content`, try it with `match_parent`.